# Azure Web App "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Tags: azure, http-status-code-401

I have been following the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=azure-resource-explorer%2Cprogramming-language-csharp to set up my web app with the Microsoft Graph API Sdk.

This works fine locally. But after I pushed it to Azure, browsing to the website started giving me the error "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I have since reverted my changes but the error still persists. I have not been able to find out why it is doing this.